# Video recording not saved properly on calling the intent "new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);"

Tags: android, camera

I have simple standard code which records video as follows

```
    public class TtActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        File videoFile;
        Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newconferencehomelayout);

        videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.mp4");

        if(!videoFile.exists()){

            try {
                    videoFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);






    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1){

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                Toast.makeText(TtActivity.this, "File saved at "+videoFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Toast.makeText(TtActivity.this, "Recording cancelled..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(TtActivity.this, "Capturing failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }




}
```

And in the manifest i have

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tt.cc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="TtActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So my problem is after recording complete the file is created but the size of the video file is 0 bytes... Hence failed to play it.. so please help me in solving this problem.. I am testing it on my htc desire mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 200);
```

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) link for more...

Comment: thx but in your code u have created you own media recorder.. instead i have to invoke the standard camera recorder so that i can use all the facilities offered by that app.. So reply on that post

Comment: I m developing it on android 2.1 which does not support.. intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 200); By d way my code actually captures video but it does not save it on mentioned file instead it stores it on its default directory..